# why doesn't the result of an array member changed when have assigned it?

Tags: arrays, c, post-increment, pre-increment

when I did something like this:

```
int arr[]={11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
int *p=arr;
*(p++) += 100;
```

The result of arr[1] was still 12,why?

Comment: Because it is a *post*-increment. Check the value of `arr[0]`.

Comment: Because you only changed the first element.

Comment: If you printed out the entire `arr` array, you would see that the first item was changed, thus would indicate to you what is happening.  FYI -- It's simple things like this (printing out values) that aren't being done which leads to questions being downvoted (lack of research).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are post-incrementing `p` which does not change `p[1]`. To change `p[1]` you need to pre-increment `p`. And then decrement `p` to obtain `p[1]`.

Example: [**`TRY IT ONLINE`**](https://godbolt.org/z/c5h7b55n5)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int arr[]={11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    int *p = arr;
    *(++p) += 100;
    p--;
    printf("%d\n", p[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `100` to the first element of the array `arr[0]` and then moving `p` to the next element `arr[1]`. This expression:

```
*(p++) += 100;
```

Is actually translated into this:

```
*p += 100;
++p;
```

Comment: so the parentheses don't work here?

Comment: @HedoesnotDICE The parenthesis work, but they do not do what you are thinking: they isolate `p++` from `*` operator. In turn, `(*p)++` will indeed increase the first element.